# ViewModel Properties in Query String are not bound when arriving at Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in an ASP.net MVC application, and I have a table of products as shown in the screenshot:

[image: table of products]

I would like the ability to filter that table of products, and I'd like the filtering to happen via the query string params (as a `GET`) so that the URL can be shared.

The ViewModel for the page is like this:

```
public class InventoryReportViewModel
{
  public SearchViewModel Search { get; set; } // 2 string props [Type and Term]
  public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }
  public PaginationViewModel Pagination { get; set; } // 3 int props [currentPage, recordsPerPage, totalRecords]
}
```

I'm using Razor helpers to draw the filter inputs, like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Search.Term, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

And also I've set up my form to use `GET` like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Inventory", "Report", FormMethod.Get))
{
   // form elements
}
```

My `ReportController.cs` has the following method that is relevant to my question here:

```
public ActionResult Inventory(string SearchTerm, string SearchType, int page = 1)
{
  var viewModel = _reportService.GetProducts(page, SearchTerm, SearchType);
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

When I pass a Search term, and click the **Filter Results** button, I do arrive at my Controller method above, but the `SearchTerm` and `SearchType` are `null`.

I know how to "hack" this to work, for example, if I do this:

```
<input type="text" name="SearchTerm" class="form-control"/>
```

Then the search term I input would be picked up by the Controller, but is there no other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you already made a `viewmodel` for `Search`

```
public SearchViewModel Search { get; set; }
```

you just need to pass it to the controller like this

```
public ActionResult Inventory(SearchViewModel Search, int page = 1
{
  var viewModel = _reportService.GetProducts(page, Search.Term, Search.Type);
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

you were getting `null` because the `textboxes` were named as `Search.Term` that is why it was not matching the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The form should be post

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Inventory", "Report", FormMethod.Post))
{
  // form elements
}
```

This can also be cleaner:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Search.Term, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

to

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Search.Term, new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

Another question,
In the razor view, do you have a model specified on the first line?